# Interpretation of the following order

Tags: order-theory

$$\text{When looking at the order }\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\},\unrhd with $$

$$x\unrhd y \Leftrightarrow 
 \left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    x\leq y  \text{  if x$\cdot$y < 0} \\
    |x|\leq |y|  \text{  if x$\cdot$y > 0}
  \end{array}\right.$$

is it correct to interpret this as follows:

when  $x \cdot y$ < 0,  one (and only one) of both should be negative therefor  $x\leq y$ (or $y\leq x$  in wich case switch x and y) in other words a negative number is always smaller than a positive number.

When $x \cdot y$ > 0 both numbers have the same sign (both positive or negative) interpreting this half of the order as: 
the one with the smallest absolute value is smallest so, the one closest to zero.

In my mind this order behaves as the regular "$\leq$ " with the sole difference that, for instance,  $$-2 \leq -6 $$ because the absolute value of -6 is bigger than that of -2.

Knowing whether i interpreted this order right or wrong will be key in solving a linked problem.

$$ $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. The subset of negative integers is ordered as if it was specular with respect to the one of positive integers.

Comment: With this interpretation, would it be correct to state that -1 is the smallest number of all?

Comment: Assuming that $-1$ is a minimum if $-1 \unrhd n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$, yes. For if $n$ is a positive integer, then $-1 \cdot n < 0$  and $-1 \leq n$, so $-1 \unrhd n$, whereas if $n$ is a negative integer, then $-1 \cdot n > 0$ and $|-1| \leq |n|$, so $-1 \unrhd n$ again.